# Running PHP Cron Job with Arguments

Tags: php, cron

Im trying to run a PHP script, once a day, on ubuntu 13.10 server with php5.

I have cron jobs set up, via ajenti control panel, verified with `crontab -l`, for this command.

```
php /path/script.php site_id=2 table=clicks
```

I have been adjusting the time while trying to get it to run, but basically I want to run it at 2am.

```
0 2 * * *
```

I have tried running the script directly, running it via `/usr/bin/php`, `/usr/bin/php5/`, and `php`, and nothing ever leaves a trace in syslog, or the apache log or error files (trace level 8)

I was trying to run it at 2am, so I set it that way, but running a `date` on the terminal shows the current time as

> Thu Feb  6 07:44:29 UTC 2014

I have tried running the cron jobs at 7something am too, and again, nothing runs.

Any ideas? Besides syslog, is there any ubuntu logging for cron jobs, to see if they run or don't and why?

Also, is that the proper way to send arguments? Does the script need to accept them any differently than a web based script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, validate your command works properly from command line:

```
/usr/bin/env php /path/to/script.php arguments
```

---

Second, validate your `cron` is running:

```
ps auxw | grep cron
```

There should be line like (highlights with `^` mine)

```
root      1537  0.0  0.0  19112   336 ?        Ss    2012   1:03 cron
^^^^                                                             ^^^^
```

---

If `cron` is running properly, check other cron messages from syslog:

```
sudo zgrep CRON /var/log/syslog*
```

By default, various tasks run as `root`, configured in `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly` etc. folders. If there's no output, your cron is not running properly. Try restarting it with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

And check contents of `/var/log/syslog` for error messages, and proceed to step 1 again

---

If `cron` is running properly, proceed to check mailbox of the user that has that command on their `crontab`. Replace USERNAME.

```
sudo -u USERNAME mail
```

or
    sudo -u USERNAME less /var/mail/USERNAME

If executing cron command fails, it should send email to there.

---

You should use `/usr/bin/env php /path/to/script.php` as your command, instead of just `php`. `/usr/bin/env` automatically selects proper `php` binary.

---

For arguments, no, you have to read arguments separately. That's off-topic for this site, but take a look at [this manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php). You can read those arguments from `$argv`. It does not work in same way as with scripts called through web server.